# Difference between EMI filter and RFI filter

Tags: pcb-design, power-electronics, filter, common-mode, emi-filtering

I always see EMI filters at power entrance of machines. They generally have a circuit something like the below:

[image]

The machine that I investigated has noise limiter filters that are called RFI filters on the internet.  I guess it is differential mode filter. Similar filter is below:

[image]

**My questions are:**

- I will use EMI filter (common mode filter) at AC power entrance. May I use both filters?
- Is diff. mode filter for suppressing the harmonics?
- Is diff. mode filter just for DC lines?

I need an expert advice for using both filters on same system.

Comment: Please link to the pdf data sheets for these products.

Answer (score 4):

EMI and RFI are broadly similar, but they are worth dividing in two classes, because of differences between sources, and how they spread.

EMI is generally low frequency, driven by rectifier noise (50/60Hz plus harmonics), switching supplies (100s kHz plus harmonics), DC motor brush noise, and environmental effects like induced or direct lightning surge.  It is conducted on wires.

RFI is generally high frequency, driven by switching noise (high harmonics, parasitic oscillations), arcing and sparking (brush noise, switch/relay open/closing), and transients such as EFT (electrical fast transients: produced when opening a switch/relay to a highly inductive load which causes rapid-fire sparking of the contact) and ESD.  It can be conducted or radiated.

I can't quite make out the inductance of the coaxial / normal-mode / RFI filter component pictured, but I think you will find they are generally available with fairly small inductances (~µH).  This is partly by necessity: as a single-ended / normal-mode / DC filter, the inductor must handle the full rated current (40A!) without saturating.  (Magnetic saturation means a sharp drop in inductance, with respect to DC bias, which would limit the filter's effectiveness.)

Whereas you will find, the EMI filters generally have quite large inductors (~mH), with dual windings applied in the common mode.  In fact they're better described as transformers, but they're being used for the series impedance, as you would an inductor; the fact that they're "inducting" two windings at once, is where the transformer action comes into play.  Besides common mode (CMC), they are also called "current compensated chokes", as the DC/mains frequency magnetization of the two windings cancel out, assuming there's no significant leakage from the circuit to ground.

The pictured type of EMI filter also provides some differential mode (DM) filtering, but with much smaller inductances (namely, the leakage inductance between windings); this is acceptable, as much larger capacitors can be used (the line-to-line, X1/X2 rated capacitors), giving adequate cutoff frequency.  (Note that the CM capacitors (line-to-ground, Y1 rated) can't be very large, lest they draw significant leakage current at mains frequency.  Typically they're up to 4.7nF.  This in turn mandates such high CM inductances.)

The RFI filter might also have a low to middling cutoff frequency, but its priority will be high attenuation over a broad RF frequency range.  That it can be mounted into a bulkhead, also helps with shielding such frequencies -- radiation means those signals couple more easily with nearby wires, or they "don't like to stay in wires", if you will.

For AC line entry, the RFI type is likely prohibited due to its large capacitance to ground.

Answer (score 3):

That round type of RFI filter is called a feed-through filter, as it is used to feed the power leads through a chassis wall while maintaining the EMI tightness of the chassis.

If your box is not EMI tight to begin with (RF gasketing between covers and chassis walls, lots of screws, shielded IO connectors, etc.), then using a feed-through connector of the type you've shown doesn't matter very much, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

The RFI filter seems mechanically configured, to fit into a metal bulkhead.

Thus the metal bulkhead serves as excellent shield between input and output wires.

Whereas the EMI filter is intended to be installed on a metal plate (notice that mounting tab on the case), with input wiring and output wiring (in the power lines) able to couple to each other by Electric Fields over the top of the EMI filter.